# Python Fizz Buzz Woof game

Tags: python

```
for num in range (1,101):
    output=" "
    if (num%3==0):
        output="Fizz"
    if(num%5==0):
        output+="Buzz"
    if (num%7==0):
        output+="Woof"

    #how many 3s do i have?
    num=str(num)
    cnt=num.count("3") #33->2
    for x in range(cnt):
        output += "Fizz"

    #how many 5s
    cnt=num.count("5")
    for x in range(cnt):
        output+="Buzz"

    cnt=num.count("7")
    for x in range(cnt):
        output+="Woof"

    if(output==" "):
        output=num
    print(output, end = " ")
```

```
1 2 FizzFizz 4  BuzzBuzz Fizz  WoofWoof 8 Fizz  Buzz 11 Fizz  Fizz  Woof FizzBuzzBuzz 16  Woof Fizz 19  Buzz FizzWoof 22  Fizz Fizz  BuzzBuzz 26 FizzWoof  Woof 29 FizzBuzzFizz  Fizz  Fizz FizzFizzFizz  Fizz  BuzzWoofFizzBuzz FizzFizz  FizzWoof  Fizz FizzFizz  Buzz 41 FizzWoof  Fizz 44 FizzBuzzBuzz 46  Woof Fizz  Woof  BuzzBuzz FizzBuzz  Buzz  FizzBuzz FizzBuzz  BuzzBuzzBuzz  WoofBuzz FizzBuzzWoof  Buzz  Buzz FizzBuzz 61 62 FizzWoofFizz 64  BuzzBuzz Fizz  Woof 68 Fizz  BuzzWoofWoof  Woof FizzWoof  FizzWoof  Woof FizzBuzzBuzzWoof  Woof  WoofWoofWoof FizzWoof  Woof  Buzz Fizz 82  Fizz FizzWoof  BuzzBuzz 86 FizzWoof 88 89 FizzBuzz  Woof 92 FizzFizz 94  BuzzBuzz Fizz  Woof  Woof Fizz  Buzz
```

IS THE RESULT. I WONDER WHY I GOT FIZZFIZZ AT NUMBER 3, BUZZBUZZ AT NUMBER 5 AND WOOFWOOF AT NUMBER 7 WHILE I ONLY NEED FIZZ FOR NO.3, BUZZ FOR NO.5 AND WOOF FOR NO.7

I WANT TO KNOW WHERE THE ERROR CAME FROM. I ALSO WANT TO KNOW THE RIGHT CODE
I KNOW IT'S A EASY CODING BUT I REALLY APPRECIATE FOR YOUR HELP

Answer (score 0):

This can be greatly simplified by using bit masks as follows:

```
fbw = {
    1: 'Fizz',
    2: 'Buzz',
    4: 'Woof',
    3: 'FizzBuzz',
    5: 'FizzWoof',
    6: 'BuzzWoof',
    7: 'FizzBuzzWoof'
}
for i in range(1, 101):
    k = int(i % 3 == 0)
    if i % 5 == 0:
        k += 2
    if i % 7 == 0:
        k += 4
    output.append(fbw.get(k, str(i)))

print(', '.join(output))
```